# react native android webview issue, pdf/docx/xlsx is not loading

Tags: android, react-native, webview

Tried with multiple prefix urls: (FINAL_URL = PREFIX_URL+DOCUMENT_URL)

Prefix urls:

1. https://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=
2. https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=

I used react-native-webview for this

```
<WebView
  source={{
    uri: `${PREFIX_URL}${attachmentUrl}`
  }}
  javaScriptEnabled={true}
  cacheEnabled={false}
  startInLoadingState={true}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you share the document with a setting allowing anyone with a link to view it? It might be that you simply have to be logged into google drive to view it.

You can test it by opening the URL in an incognito tab